# Anything / something / nothing and ... as a subject

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Can you please explain these kinds of pronouns?
The verb after these pronouns is singular or plural?

For Example:

> No one but athletes **understand / understands** this problem.

> Everybody except weirdos **like / likes** pizza.

> Nobody at these parties ever **say / says** hi.

> Anyone from the States **recognize / recognizes** the flag.

> Everyone in these groups **belong / belongs**.

Comment: Your all sentences require s, but if you use the word “but” as only, or athletes is the subject of that verb in your first example, then you don’t need to add s since it is plural.

Comment: *No-one but my wife **understands** me* (***wife*** is ***singular***). *No-one but my children **understand** me* (***children*** are ***plural***).

Comment: But I found this from [Jane Austen: Reflections of a Reader](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Jane_Austen/-uEbEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22No-one+but+her+children%22&pg=PT79&printsec=frontcover) (2021) - *no one but her children **has** any continuous existence in her thoughts at all.* AND from [Beethoven in Vienna](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22no+one+but+her+children+are+admitted%22) (2014) *The site of death where no one but her children **are** admitted*. So it's six of one and half-a-dozen of the other, with no real consistency.

Comment: My advice is to just rephrase if there seems to be any doubt as to the plurality of "no-one but X" (regardless of whether X is singular or plural). That's what sensible native speakers always do.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, sir, I agree with you!

Comment: @JayHo: It may vary according to *exact* context - but by and large, ***Only** X does it* will be a suitable alternative to ***No-one but** X does it*. Technically speaking, there should be no difference between *No-one **does** it / Everyone **does** it* and *No-one **except X** does it / Everyone **except X** does it* (syntactically, the "except" element is just an optional adjectival modifier). But as my examples clearly show (they're both 100% valid, imho), we can't easily define any fixed rule here, so if you're not sure what "sounds right", just ***steer clear**!*